# Annuities problem

Tags: finance, financial-engineering

First problem is like this:

loan amount: 20,000,000.00

First six months: There is no payment but there are interest (grace period)

Next six months: payment of 600,000.00

Since 13 month: payment of R

Term: 3 years

Interest rate:

First year: 1% effective monthly

Second year:1.5% effective monthly

Third year: 2% effective monthly

Find R value

Answer from textbook 954,066.98

My attempt: I put focal date on month six, then i move 20M to focal date and late i tried to move all payments to my focal date

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+21020201%3D600000%281-%281%2B0.01%29^-6%29%2F0.01%2Bx%28%281-%281%2B0.015%29^-6%29%2F0.015%29*%281%2B0.015%29^-6%2Bx*%28%281-%281%2B0.02%29^-12%29%2F0.02%29*%281%2B0.02%29^-18

But i guess that was, 'cause wolfram answer is really far from textbook

Comment: Hi @LenaVonEngel and welcome to quant.SE! Please, read the FAQ in the help center to see what questions you can post here. This one could be close because considered an off-topic question